# Adding .asmx to Nancy in .NET 4.5.2 - not supported after HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, nancy

I am trying add an old .asmx web service to Nancy-based app. Per suggestions on other SO posts, I have already added

```
<add key="wcf:serviceHostingEnvironment:useClassicReadEntityBodyMode" value="true" />
```

but to no avail, I still get

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. --->
>   System.Web.HttpException: This method or property is not supported
>   after HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream has been invoked.
>          at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type,
>   HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
>   Boolean& abortProcessing)

If I comment out `app.UseNancy(options)` the asmx works again. In fact, it even works without the `useClassicReadEntityBodyMode`. How can I make asmx work with Nancy? For Startup, I

```
var bootstrapper = new CustomNinjectNancyBootstrapper(resolver.Kernel);
var options = new NancyOptions
{
    Bootstrapper = bootstrapper,
    PerformPassThrough = c => c.Request.Path.EndsWith(".asmx"),
};
options.PassThroughWhenStatusCodesAre(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
app.UseNancy(options);
app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
```

Update, the SOAP client is .NET 3.5, could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not Nancy, it was `app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);` which I removed. This is an Owin question so I'm closing.